# USer Control Custom event and set get property

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have 2 labels and a property in user control: 
Here is property:

```
private int _SelectIndex;
[Browsable(true)]
public int SelectIndex { get; set; }
```

and 2 labels:

```
Label lbl1, lbl2;
void iControl()
{
      lbl1 = new Label();
      lbl2 = new Label();
      lbl1.Name = "lbl1";
      lbl2.Name = "lbl2";
      lbl1.Click += lbl_Click;
      lbl2.Click += lbl_Click;
      this.Controls.Add(lbl1);
      this.Controls.Add(lbl2);
}
```

Click:

```
void lbl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label selectedlbl = sender as Label;
    if(selectedlbl.Name == "lbl1") 
          this.Select = 1;
    else
          this.Select = 2;
}
```

Class Event:

```
public class SelectEventArgs : EventArgs
{
  private int index;
  public SelectEventArgs(int index)
  {
     this.index = index;
  }

  public int ItemIndex
  {
    get
    {
      return index;
    }
  }
}
```

Custom event in my control:

```
public event EventHandler SelectEvent;
protected virtual void OnSelectEvent()
{
  if (SelectEvent!= null)
    SelectEvent(this, new SelectEventArgs(this._SelectIndex));
}
```

I need an event to get and set property value in MainForm as following:

```
int index = 0;
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  this.icontrol = new iControl();
  this.SelectEvent += Select();
}

void Select(object sender, SelectItem e)
{
   //use this to set value of Select
   this.icontrol.SelectIndex = index;
   //and this to get value of Select
   index = this.icontrol.SelectIndex;
}
```

Select is empty.
How to get it to work?

Comment: What part is failing here, by the looks of it this will work.

Comment: I wonder I can add an event as ListBox.SelectIndex@jbmintjb

Comment: Ah listbox, didn't mention that one! My answer is below.

Comment: **1-** Are you sure the `Form1` compiles? `SelecetEvent` does't belong to the `Form`, it belongs to `icontrol`.  **2-** `this.SelectEvent += Select();` is incorrect, you should use `icontrol.SelectEvent += Select;`. **3-** When you created a custom event args, you should define the event this way: `public event EventHandler<SelectEventArgs>  SelectEvent;`.

Answer (score 1):

The code has multiple issues. Consider these tips to solve the issues:

1. `SelecetEvent` does't belong to the `Form`. The event belongs to `icontrol`.
2. `this.SelectEvent += Select();` is incorrect, you should use:

   ```
   icontrol.SelectEvent += Select;
   ```
3. When you have a custom event args, you should define the event this way:

   ```
   public event EventHandler<SelectEventArgs> SelectEvent;
   ```
4. You should raise the event in setter of your property, using `OnSelectEvent` method which you created.

To learn more about events take a look at [C# Handling and Raising Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thank for your suggest. still nothing._SelectIndex is empty@Reza Aghaei

Comment: EventHandler. Thank you Reza Aghaei. create a method virtual void OnSelectIndexChanged and call it in selectIndex setter: OnSelectIndexChanged(new SelectEventArgs(value));.It worked!  @Reza Aghaei

Comment: You're welcome :) `OnSelectIndexChanged` is not necessary, your event is enough. I added another tip to the answer.

Comment: will pay attention to that.I think it is worth voteup for helpful@Reza Aghaei

Comment: Btw, When you accept an answer, like your last post, it would be great if you also vote for the answer by click on up arrow near the post. It's not compulsory at all, but it's common, reasonable and recommended. For more information about how does accepting answers work see this [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow).

Answer (score 1):

I post here for any one need it:
1.Declare a delegate:

```
public delegate void SelectIndexEventHandler(object sender, SelectEventArgs e);
public class SelectEventArgs : EventArgs
{
  private int index;
  public SelectEventArgs(int index)
  {
    this.index = index;
  }

  public int ItemIndex
  {
    get { return index; }
    set { index = value; }
  }
}
```

2. declare an event SelectIndexChanged and a method OnSelectIndexChanged:

```
public event SelectIndexEventHandler SelectIndexChanged;
protected virtual void OnSelectIndexChanged(SelectEventArgs e)
{
   if (SelectIndexChanged != null)
      SelectIndexChanged(this, e);
}
```

3.Call it in setter:

```
public int SelectIndex
{
   get { return _SelectIndex; }
   set { 
     _SelectIndex = value;
     OnSelectIndexChanged(new SelectEventArgs(value)); 
   }
}
```

and then MainForm:

```
this.gListBox1.SelectIndexChanged += icontrol_SelectIndexChanged;
void icontrol_SelectIndexChanged(object sender, SelectEventArgs e)
{
   var current = e.ItemIndex;
}
```

thank again jbmintjb Reza Aghaei.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [SelectedIndexChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event on the listbox control, think that is what you are looking for

Comment: Oh!I need an event SetSelected.But I don't know how to get it@jbmintjb

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.setselected(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thank you! I'm trying to get selected label in my control. But I can't.please see my updated@jbmintjb

Comment: In this line here -  this.icontrol.Select = index; what is index?

Comment: it is selected label.what is selected@jbmintjb